# What is the equivalent operation of measures to the multiplication of (right-continuous, bounded variation) function

Tags: measure-theory, bounded-variation, signed-measures

Consider the spaces

- $\mathcal{M}$ the set of all finite, signed measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$
- $\Phi$ the set of all right-continuous functions $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with bounded variation and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$

Then the projection $$\mu\mapsto F_\mu(x):= \mu(]-\infty,x])\,, x\in\mathbb{R}$$
is an isomorphism. Further, we can equip $\Phi$ and $\mathcal{M}$ with the total variation norms (for functions and measures respectively).
Then, because $F\cdot G\in\Phi$ and because both spaces are isomorphic, there has to be an equivalent operation on $\mathcal{M}$ to the multiplication of functions in $\Phi$.

Does someone know how this operation is defined on $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: $\mu.\nu=\tau$ where $\tau (-\infty,x])=F(x)G(x)$.

Comment: Okay but this is just using the operation on $\Phi$. The question is, if it's possible to have an equivalent operation just using measures. Especially one that is not limited to finite, signed measures for which we can use the isomorphism.

Comment: This theorem you mention really amounts to its corollary:  given $\mu,\nu\in \mathcal{M}$, there is a unique signed measure $\tau$ such that on all elements of generating set $\{(-\infty, x] : x\in\mathbf{R}\}$ of $\mathscr{B}$, $\tau((-\infty,x])=\mu((-\infty,x]))\nu((-\infty,x])$. It is not in general true that such a $\tau$ exists or is unique. Geetha's remark is the ***unique*** way to turn your assignment $\mathcal{M}\to \Phi$ into a isomorphism of $\mathbf{R}$-algebras (likely Banach algebras, even).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm not quite sure if we are talking about the same thing though. It is clear to me that Geetha's remark is a characterization of this operation but it is one that relying on the transformation of the measure into its corresponding function. I was wondering if there is a operation in the measure space that doesn't require this (but is of course equivalent since the spaces are isomorphic). Maybe I'm just confused about the definitions?

Comment: Perhaps—it's not totally clear to me what "equivalent" means to you, but to Geetha and myself it means exactly what they've said. If you unpack what these words mean, you'll find that the association is the one sending $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal{M}$ to the (unique!) finite signed measure $\tau$ for which $\tau((-\infty,x])=\mu((-\infty,x])\nu((-\infty,x])$ which—as I said above—is what I think the content of this theorem is. In other words, if $\mu\cdot\nu=\tau$ and $\varphi\colon\mathcal{M}\to\Phi$ is your assignment, then $\varphi(\mu\cdot\nu)=\varphi(\mu)\varphi(\nu)=\varphi(\tau)$.

Comment: And I suppose it's worth reiterating that such a $\tau$ is not guaranteed to exist or be unique in general. Finiteness is what makes this go, as I understand it (albeit I haven't thought much about this stuff in like 7 years).